# Rendered rectangles do not move with chart when scrolling

Tags: highcharts, renderer

I want to draw a rectangle on a chart and have it move with the rest of the chart.  However, it stays where it was originally rendered in pixel coordinates.

I would have thought there would be a way to add annotations such as this in world coordinates rather than screen coordinates, but I was not able to find a way.  Is such a thing possible?

Assuming I am stuck with annotating in screen coordinates, what event(s) do I need to handle to redraw the rectangle when the user zooms or scrolls?

Simple example:

```
chart.renderer.rect(chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(1432897200000),chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(1.09674),14,14, 0)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bz3t79p5/

Also, I have had no luck with using axis.toPixels() for setting the rectangle's width and height.  I was getting values that were way out of whack.  Is there a trick to converting width and height from world coordinates to pixels?

Comment: Use [redraw](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.redraw) event to redraw all of your objects using `.attr()` or just use [Annotations plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/17/Annotations).

Comment: Annotations plugin looks promising, but, again, the rectangles don't scale with zoom.  It looks like only the path annotation can scale.  Am I reading that right?

Comment: Yes, default rect doesn't scale by width/height.